# Entity Framework cardinality in a 1..1 or 1..0 relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an entity which has a self reference such that a Member can have a Witness who has to be a member and may also have a Reference who has to be a member. I modeled this as follows;

```
public class Member
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //omitted for brevity
        public int? WitnessId { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Witness { get; set; }

        public int? ReferenceId { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Reference { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run the update-database on package manager console, I get the following error:
"XXX.Client.Entities.Member' and 'XXX.Client.Entities.Member'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."

Any idea on how this can be resolved?

Comment: Did you configure the relationship with fluent api? Should we help you with this?

Comment: @mr100 YES, I configured the relationship with fluent api. I tried soemthing like `modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().HasOptional(x=>x.Witness)`... but still didn't work.

Comment: Please add then to your post code for fluent api configuration of this relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define relationship with fluent api this way (works for me):

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().HasOptional(x => x.Witness)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.WitnessId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().HasOptional(x => x.Reference)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.ReferenceId);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be working:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {


        modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().
            HasOptional(e => e.Witness).
            WithMany().
            HasForeignKey(m => m.WitnessID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().
            HasOptional(e => e.Reference).
            WithMany().
            HasForeignKey(m => m.ReferenceID);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
```

Comment: thanx, it's similar to what mr100 answered.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work for those of us who prefer to have things in the class deriving from the EntityTypeConfiguration

```
class MemberEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Member>
{
    public MemberEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        HasOptional(x => x.Witness).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.WitnessId);
        HasOptional(x => x.Reference).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.ReferenceId);
    }
}
```